# What are four ways to quadrisect any triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

What are four ways to quadrisect any triangle with compass and straightedge? I have a few already:

1. Draw a median and from the midpoint, draw two medians to the remaining sides.
2. Draw a median and from the point from which it is drawn, draw two medians, quadrisecting the one side.
3. Draw a horizontal midline, and from the intersection points, draw two lines to the midpoint of the base.

They have to be constructable with a compass and an unmarked straightedge, and must divide the triangle into four pieces with equal area, but they do not have to be similar to the original triangle.

Comment: Do the pieces have to have the same area?  Be similar to the original triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint without words:

[image]

Hint 2:

[image]

(Ignore this sentence.)

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what you did. Is that even constructable?

Comment: @asdf: It's constructible ... and if you could see exactly what I did, then it wouldn't be a *hint*. ;)  Here's another hint: a red segment, a green segment, and a blue segment are parts of lines that meet at a special point.

Comment: Is it the incenter?

Comment: It is not the incenter. Another hint: The construction is *just as easy* as the three you provided.

Comment: Those are medians, so isn't that the incenter? Or have I mixed up my points...

Comment: Medians, indeed! (So, not *incenter*, but *centroid*.) Medians, medians, medians! Medians *everywhere*! (Some you can't even see.)

Comment: oh I see, but what are the other lines?

Comment: @asdf: Medians, medians, medians ...

Comment: I'm so confused... medians to what?

Comment: @asdf: I'll let you ponder that for a while. But I'll make this observation: (Ignoring the blue, red, green ...) The lines to the centroid *tri*-sect the triangle's area. How much of each of those three sub-triangles do the blue, red, and green sub-sub-triangles cover?

Comment: 1/4 of the total

Comment: @asdf: "1/4 of the total" is *how much* of each third?

Comment: 3/4? asdfadsfasdf

Comment: @asdf: Yup. Now ... If only you knew some way to carve a triangle into quarters, so that you could take three of them ...

Comment: Oh, thanks so much! :)